# Get path as shown to user (as opposed to path used by C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When connecting an Android device to a PC, the path to a file is not the path we use in Xamarin.

For example, the path we use is `/storage/emulated/0/somePath`, but the path shown to a user is something like `phone/card/somePath`.

How do we get the path that the user sees? Even if we don't know the drive letter, that's fine.

Comment: The path used by the system is the only one that truly matters. Anything different displayed to the user has simply been faked; you can show the user whatever you want to. If you know that the device storage path is `/storage/emulated/0/...`, you can opt to just strip that whole path off whatever you print back to the display.

Comment: @MattClark I wouldn't like to hard code `/storage/emulated/0/`. Not all paths are like that, and I don't know if that will change. And I don't even know if all devices will have the exact same path. Different Android phones work quite differently from each other.

Comment: That path should not be hard coded, but should come from one of your APIs. I don't know xamarin, but Android has API calls for [saving files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html). You should use something like [`getExternalFilesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) to return the root path of your SD card, then just remove whatever this text is from the path that you display to the user.

Comment: @MattClark That seems like a good idea. I need to see if that'll work.